# How to reset a React-Native checkbox component

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am writing an application in React Native and have written a checkbox component which appears inside a popup dialog which appears when a user clicks a View.

Now this flows like this:

1. The checkbox component is rendered within popup dialog for 8 times by using [...Array(8)].map() as a list of checkboxes
2. I click on View, the popup dialog appears
3. I select few Pickers and checks multiple checkboxes (this is a stateful component which has its own this.state and manages its own checked states along with callback function passed via props to retrieve checked states and selected values in parent component)
4. If I click outside the popup dialog, the popup dialog dismisses and should reset all the checboxes to false

I've achieved the first three but stuck on 4th since yesterday. Tried implementing Refs, reset via componentWillReceiveProps and now even tried adding key to the component which is assigned timestamp for the component to reset itself (checked state = false) when the popup dialog dismisses / disappears. As of now when the popup dialog dismisses and reopens, the previously checked checkbox(es) are still checked.

Awaiting for your much needed help.

Thanks and best,

Rohit

Comment: Just reset states of Checkboxes on ComponentWillUnmount

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Tried that mate, that wouldn't fire when popup dialog dismisses